# SQL joins - 3 nested levels and the deepest level doesn't display data

Tags: sql, left-join

I tried to do a nested join.

I tested each of them and it works, but when I put all together it doesn't display the deepest join data.

That one from `t1(LEFT JOIN BUG ON RELEASES.REL_ID = BUG.BG_TARGET_REL OR RELEASES.REL_ID = BG_DETECTED_IN_REL) AS t1)`.

My SQL comes from HP ALM tables with relationship tables that I am using
[image]

```
Select
  // REQ
  REQ.RQ_REQ_ID /*Exigence.ID exigence*/,
  REQ.RQ_FATHER_ID /*Exigence.Dossier parent*/,

  // REQ_COVER
  t0.RC_ENTITY_ID /*Couverture de l'exigence.ID entité de couverture*/,
  t0.RC_ITEM_ID /*Couverture de l'exigence.ID unique d'élément de couverture*/,
  t0.RC_REQ_ID /*Couverture de l'exigence.Exigence*/,
  // TEST
  t0.TS_TEST_ID /*Test.ID test*/,

  // REQ_RELEASES
  t2.RQRL_REQ_ID /*Lien des exigences aux mises à jour.ID exigence*/,
  t2.RQRL_ID /*Lien des exigences aux mises à jour.ID*/,
  t2.RQRL_RELEASE_ID /*Lien des exigences aux mises à jour.ID mise à jour*/,
  // RELEASES
  t2.REL_ID /*Mise à jour.ID mise à jour*/,

  // BUG
  t2.BG_BUG_ID

  from REQ

    Left Join
       (SELECT *  FROM REQ_COVER
          LEFT JOIN TEST ON REQ_COVER.RC_ENTITY_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID
          ) AS t0 
    ON t0.RC_REQ_ID = REQ.RQ_REQ_ID

Left Join

       (SELECT * FROM REQ_RELEASES
          LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT * FROM RELEASES
                     LEFT JOIN BUG ON RELEASES.REL_ID = BUG.BG_TARGET_REL OR RELEASES.REL_ID = BG_DETECTED_IN_REL
                     ) AS t1

        ON REQ_RELEASES.RQRL_ID = t1.REL_ID) AS t2


//REQ_RELEASES
  ON REQ.RQ_REQ_ID = t2.RQRL_ID

  WHERE REQ.RQ_FATHER_ID = 21
```

Comment: Why not indent?  Why would anyone want to read this code that isn't indented

Comment: @Hogan the more time I spend on SO the more time I realize that most "bugs" are just hidden misspellings in poorly-formatted code. The in-line commenting between the columns and each comma is exceptionally hard to parse here.

Comment: @JacobH -- that was my point but I was trying to use the Socratic method. :)

Comment: @Hogan At the risk of sounding pedantic and creepy in the current social & political climate, I would offer this quote from one of my favorite movies (Seven). "Wanting people to listen, you can't just tap them on the shoulder anymore. You have to hit them with a sledgehammer, and then you'll notice you've got their strict attention." Unfortunately on SO this seems to translate to "I don't really care what the problem is I just need someone else to solve it for me ASAP"... :)

Comment: @JacobH -- Cute quote.  However, the OP edited the source -- it is now indented.  My ego assumes it was my comment that prompted it.  :8

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
REQ.RQ_REQ_ID = t2.RQRL_ID
```

be

```
ON REQ.RQ_REQ_ID = t2.RQRL_REQ_ID
```

**Explanation**

It seems like RQRL_ID is the primary key for REQ_RELEASES based on clue #1 ordinal position of the columns suggest that the first column is the unique constraint, primary key. Clue #2 RQRL_ID sounds similarly like REQ_RELEASE ID so it would be hard to imagine that it is the foreign key that should be used to join to RQ_REQ_ID. However, RQRL_REQ_ID does sound like the foreign key that should be used to join to REQ.RQ_REQ_ID. That's of course if you pronounce REQ like /rek/. See what uniform naming convention can do for a newcomer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 problems

The first:

```
AS t1 ON REQ_RELEASES.RQRL_ID = t1.REL_ID
```

should be

```
AS t2 on REQ_RELEASES.RQRL_REALEASE_ID = t1.REL_PARENT_ID
```

And second:

```
REQ.RQ_REQ_ID = t2.RQRL_ID
```

should be

```
ON REQ.RQ_REQ_ID = t2.RQRL_REQ_ID
```